# iterate list of values from hashmap in FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

I need iterate the hash map in freemarker.

My hash map value :

```
 {
  key : [{"a":"c"},{"a":"d"}]
}
```

Need to iterate this value like

```
<#list map?keys as key>
    ${values} = ${map.get(key)}
    <#list values as value>
     <div>${value.a}</div>
    </#list>  
</#list>
```

But am getting the exception:

```
content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence):
```

How to iterate this am using freemarker 2.3.20.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `<#assign values = map.get(key)>` instead of `${values} = ${map.get(key)}`

Comment: @JasperdeVries that map have the list of values but its returning null or missing exception

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<#list map as key, values>
  <#list values as value>
   <div>${value.a}</div>
  </#list>  
</#list>
```

Also if you need to access values in a map by key, other than listing them in pairs (like above), the syntax is `map[key]`, not `map.get(key)` (barring some setups where you have to use the Java API).